can't build app bundle for android project from terminal
./gradlew bundleRelease throws
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Data Fielder'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.firebase.crashlytics:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.gradle.plugin:3.0.2
      > No matching variant of com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 679ms

gradle version : ./gradlew --version
Gradle 8.7
java version : java -version
openjdk version "11.0.24" 2024-07-16


Your post only contains the gradle error output. Usually questions on Stackoverflow should contain an actual question and mor einformation. Anyway if you would just read the error output you would find the problem, it is already contained in there. See the line Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with...

Yellow,
When you run this command using Android Studio, the system uses the correct Java version that you set in your project configuration. However, when you run the command using the command line (./gradlew), the Java version used is the one present on the machine.
You can check the Java version by running the following command:
java -version

For example, in your case, the system has Java 11 but requires Java 17. You can solve the problem by changing your machine’s Java version to 17.
For example:
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk

